# Entity Framework Core: No parameterless constructor defined for this dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a problem when I try to generate a new scaffold with Entity Framework Core. I get an error

> No parameterless constructor defined for this dbcontext.

I've tried any solution but nothing works.

This is the my dbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PlayerAdvanceStats> PlayerAdvanceStats { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
            .HasOne(a => a.PlayerAdvanceStats)
            .WithOne(a => a.player)
            .HasForeignKey<PlayerAdvanceStats>(c => c.PlayerId);
        }
    }
```

I've added this in my `Startup` file inside the `ConfigureService` method:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Did you try adding the empty constructor?

Comment: Could you add the command that you used and is causing the error? Are the startup project and the project with the context the same? In a normal set up the DI specified in the startup project is used to create the dbcontext.

Comment: Are you sure that's the error and not `System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`? Emphasis on `object`.

Comment: hi yes I'm sure

Comment: How are you instantiating your dbcontext (`MyDbContext`)?

Comment: The context is configure in the startup file

Comment: Right, but how are you using it in your code? Do you have an example of injection or using `new` to create an instance of it? Is it a parameter in any constructors?

Comment: I use DI inside the controller API

Comment: @stefanotoppi could you add the complete command that is causing the error in your OP it will shed more insight in the problem. Also, add a bit more about how your solution looks like.

Comment: Can you add that code to your question? The issue is happening when you or the runtime tries to construct your dbcontext. We need to see that in your question to best answer you.

Comment: The description suggests that it's the scaffolding tool that is triggering the error. That might be worth clearing up.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

If the CLI can't get the context from the dependency container it will either try to find a default constructor or a design time factory. Before you do either of those you need to ask yourself why it can't find the context in your container.

Is the context in a different project then the project with the host builder then you need to use the -s flag to specify the startup project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `DbContext` class:

```cs
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
        // try adding the parameterless constructor indicated by the error
        public MyDbContext() : base() { }

        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PlayerAdvanceStats> PlayerAdvanceStats { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
            .HasOne(a => a.PlayerAdvanceStats)
            .WithOne(a => a.player)
            .HasForeignKey<PlayerAdvanceStats>(c => c.PlayerId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't necessary (or correct) according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/). OP must have done something else that we aren't seeing.